# Get stack trace of exceptions in heap

Tags: .net, windbg, crash-dumps

I use WinDbg and I want to get exception details. With help of  `!dumpheap -type Exception` command get a list of exceptions in dump but how can I access these exception details?

```
000007fef84e1298        1          160 System.StackOverflowException
000007fef84e1220        1          160 System.OutOfMemoryException

000007fef84e1388        2          320 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
000007fef84e1038        2          320 System.Exception
000007fef84ec220        6          384 System.UnhandledExceptionEventHandler
000007fef746ea90       10         1760 System.Net.WebException
000007fef84ed780      131        22008 System.ObjectDisposedException
```

Answer (score 9):

### !do

Rerun the `!dumpheap` command without `-stat` to get the object addresses, then you can access the details with `!do <address>` or `!dumpobject <address>`.

Note that some of the Exceptions (StackOverflowException, OutOfMemoryException and ThreadAbortException) exist in every program, even in simple hello world applications. They are pre-allocated, because new memory might not be available at the time of throwing it.

Also note that the exceptions needn't be thrown. A `var ex = new Exception()` will create an object but not throw it. Thus they may not have  a call stack.

This is how it may look like:

```
0:003> !dumpheap -type NotImplementedException
         Address               MT     Size
000000000278a070 000007feebe03870      136     
total 1 objects
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007feebe03870        1          136 System.NotImplementedException
Total 1 objects

0:003> !do 000000000278a070 
Name: System.NotImplementedException
MethodTable: 000007feebe03870
EEClass: 000007feeb311568
Size: 136(0x88) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
[...]
000007feeb627680  40000bc       40        System.Object  0 instance 000000000278a1b8 _stackTrace
000007feeb627d90  40000bd       48        System.String  0 instance 0000000000000000 _stackTraceString
000007feeb627d90  40000be       50        System.String  0 instance     
[...]
```

If the stack trace is present, use `!pe <address>` to see it. Otherwise it it just a list of unresolved addresses in memory.

```
0:003> !pe 000000000278a070 
Exception object: 000000000278a070
Exception type: System.NotImplementedException
Message: This method does nothing but thorwing this exception.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000000135F2C0 000007FF0017067F MultiException!MultiException.Program.ThrowException2()+0x5f
    000000000135F300 000007FEEB4E2BBC mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x9c
    000000000135F350 000007FEEB57AADE mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()+0x4e

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004001
```

Due to the high number of exceptions, you might want to automate it with a foreach loop:

```
.foreach (ex {!dumpheap -type Exception -short}){ !do ${ex} }
```

### !pe

For exceptions that are currently thrown, use `!threads` to determine the threads that threw an exception. In this example, there are 4 threads with exceptions (scroll right to see it):

```
0:003> !threads
ThreadCount: 6
UnstartedThread: 0
BackgroundThread: 2
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 0
Hosted Runtime: no
                                              PreEmptive                                                Lock
       ID OSID        ThreadOBJ     State   GC     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
   0    1 251c 00000000003deff0   201a220 Enabled  00000000027846f8:0000000002785fd0 0000000000382ca0     0 MTA
   2    2 2b10 0000000000a88280      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000382ca0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
   3    3 255c 0000000000aacac0      b020 Enabled  00000000027862b8:0000000002787fd0 0000000000382ca0     0 MTA System.ArgumentException (0000000002786090)
   4    4 2a48 0000000000aad5b0      b020 Enabled  000000000278a290:000000000278bfd0 0000000000382ca0     0 MTA System.NotImplementedException (000000000278a070)
   5    5 2e50 0000000000aa20d0      b020 Enabled  0000000002788268:0000000002789fd0 0000000000382ca0     0 MTA System.OutOfMemoryException (0000000002788048)
   6    6  d50 0000000000aa2e00      b020 Enabled  000000000278c280:000000000278dfd0 0000000000382ca0     0 MTA System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException (000000000278c060)
```

<sub>How can you have 4 exceptions in one dump? This may be an exercise for the reader.</sub>

In that case, you can switch to the thread using `~ns` where n is the ID in the second column. Or use `~ne !pe` to run a command directly on that thread, e.g. like this:

```
0:003> ~3e !pe
Exception object: 0000000002786090
Exception type: System.ArgumentException
Message: This method does not have arguments.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000000112F100 000007FF0017055F MultiException!MultiException.Program.ThrowException1()+0x5f
    000000000112F140 000007FEEB4E2BBC mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x9c
    000000000112F190 000007FEEB57AADE mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()+0x4e

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80070057

0:003> ~4e !pe
Exception object: 000000000278a070
Exception type: System.NotImplementedException
Message: This method does nothing but thorwing this exception.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000000135F2C0 000007FF0017067F MultiException!MultiException.Program.ThrowException2()+0x5f
    000000000135F300 000007FEEB4E2BBC mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x9c
    000000000135F350 000007FEEB57AADE mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()+0x4e

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004001
```

Comment: Hi thomas when I want to use "!pe" --> The current thread is unmanaged,Another command "!do 00000001e7894370"
Name:        System.ObjectDisposedException
MethodTable: 000007fef84ed780
EEClass:     000007fef7ecb810
Size:        168(0xa8) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll.But I want to see stack trace of this ,for example I get this exception method b in my class a.I want to see this exception provisions in my code.

Comment: @Bilgehan: I enriched my answer with examples

Answer (score 1):

I download and install netext extension of windbg.And netext  **!wdae** command(Dump all exceptions in the heap) is another option to see exceptions.