# WinDbg display CLR (c#) exceptions using SOS

Tags: windbg, managed, sos

I have started debugging c# program using WinDbg.

Initially used GFlags to put break point on a very begin as it crashes asap it's being run.

From WinDbg after fetching gflag's break point, doing continue ("g") it proceeds execution and crashes at the end with the trace:

[image: trace]

I have crossed custom .dll-s as they're confidential.

If I am not wrong "**e0434352**" stands for a very generic CLR exception.

Is there any way how to could I inject SOS into WinDbg to make this trace more precise? e.g. How to translate these generic e0434352 exceptions into C# ones to find the exact cause of the problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place for tutorials. Please use resources such as Tess' site to study more on what to expect when debugging, https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/ First chance exceptions should be ignored (aka try-catch blocks in C# code) and you should focus on the actual issue you wanted to troubleshoot (process crash or hang). Tess provided very detailed action plan and steps to guide you analyze process crash.

Comment: The duplicate is for loading SOS. Use [`!pe` to see the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438522/get-stack-trace-of-exceptions-in-heap)

Comment: E0434352 aka E0"CCR" are generic clr exception these normally have an _Hresult associated with them like HResult is 80070057      xcode is E0434352      Value does not fall within the expected range. for ArgumentException() if you have source you can probably register for FirstChanceException Notification and examine the _HResult and _meesage programmatically  !pe in sos.dll prints thsi_Hresult and _meesage on the Exception Object